# Different controller action in Pjax gridview yii2

Tags: gridview, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i have `gridview` in `pjax`
and on its `Actioncolumn` button i am calling different `controller` action.

For example my gridview is on `event index` page and its controller is `EventController`, but on that gridview's one of the `actioncolumn` button , i am calling `CheckinController` action.

Which is working very fine only if i dont use the `Pjax` otherwise it only refreshes the `gridview` and the `url` also changes but it doesnt refreshes the page

here is the code of the `event` gridview

```
<h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
<?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>
<div class="common-button">
<p>
    <?= Html::a('Create Event', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) ?>
</p>
</div>



<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'rowOptions'=> function($modal, $key, $index, $grid) {

        if ($modal->is_active == '0') {
            return ['class' => 'danger action-tr' ];
        } else
            return ['class' => 'success action-tr'];

    },
    'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'interest_id',
            'label' => 'Event Category',
            'value' => 'interest.area_intrest',
        ],
        'title',
        'description:html',
        'location',
        'start_date',
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{checkin/index} {view} {update} {delete} ',
            'contentOptions' => ['class'=>'action-td'],
            'buttons' => [
                'checkin/index' => function ($url) {
                    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>', $url);
                },
            ]
        ],
    ]
]);
 ?>
```

Comment: try to use `[data-pjax => false]` in anchor tag of button.

Comment: @gamitg like this? `return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>', $url,['data-pjax' => false]);` That is not working. I am searching for proper syntax if the syntax is wrong.

Comment: try to change with `['data-pjax' => true]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to add `[ 'data-pjax' => true ]` in anchor tag options of `actionColumn` button.

Like as,

```
    [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{checkin/index} {view} {update} {delete} ',
            'contentOptions' => ['class'=>'action-td'],
            'buttons' => [
                'checkin/index' => function ($url) {
                    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>', $url, ['data-pjax' => true]);
                },
            ]
    ],
```